# Story from 1970s or earlier entitled maybe Passing?

Tags: story-identification

Not sure of title but I think the idea was to juxtapose an alien passing as human with a human whom he had befriended, maybe a young woman, passing as White? Can't remember much more than that -- nothing really useful.

If it is about what I recall and from half a century or more ago, maybe it is one of the earliest scifi stories to deal with Black/White relations -- I would be very surprised if this was written before 1960.

Comment: Is it "Pennies, Off a Dead Man's Eyes" by Harlan Ellison? See this old Q&A: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263825/a-hobo-goes-to-visit-a-funeral-in-the-american-south-and-proves-to-be-an-alien

Comment: No, not Ellison's story, I see you commented on that old question.

Comment: @user14111 -- sounds close and i have certainly read it -- I think Harlan E. was a fave in my circles -- but if there is a story called Passing with a similar theme I would tend to choose that.

Comment: @user14111: wow, i had forgotten and it was not that long ago. Sounds like I thought then as I do now that a separate story exists. But memory is a tricky thing -- importantly, far less reliable than we know, right? I had some lapses that had someone not been around to tell me, I would not have realized it and since that time, I have even graver doubts about my own memory.

Comment: ISFDB lists 5 stories with the exact title "Passing." The earliest was published in *Aboriginal SF* in 1987. I only skimmed it, but it seems to be about two space aliens passing as humans, not black passing as white. You can read it at https://archive.org/details/Aboriginal_Science_Fiction_Annual_Anthology_1988/page/n71/mode/2up

Comment: @user14111 - The latter three are all too late to be what OP is after; 1990s and 2000s

Comment: The "passing as white" comment makes me think the author was almost certainly referencing Harlem Renaissance author Nella Larsen's novel [*Passing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passing_(novel)).